# How I can monitor Azure SQL database hardware

Tags: sql-server, performance, azure, monitoring

I would like to monitor hardware of my Azure SQL database. Usually, I use performance counters in perfmon to collect data and later analyze it. But I can't access underlying instance of Azure sql database and setup usual set of counters... How you would suggest to monitor such things as CPU usage or disk queue of Azure database?

Comment: Have you looked [at this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-monitor/)?

Comment: @paqogomez How is it related to the SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since SQL Database (SQL Azure) is a multi-tenant Platform-as-a-Service offering, you cannot monitor the hardware it is running on, just like you can not monitor the hardware that Azure Storage is running on, or Service Bus or Media services.

You can use Data Management Views http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394114.aspx to monitor certain aspects of your database behaviour.

For an automated 24/7 way to monitor data management views and thus SQL Azure, check out a product called CloudMonix (http://cloudmonix.com - disclaimer, I work for the company)